# BLE connection established by bluetoothctl disconnect automatically

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, bluez

I have 2 raspberry pi. I set them as ble (bluetooth low energy) gatt server and client to communicate to each other.

On the server-side, I use https://github.com/Jumperr-labs/python-gatt-server to establish the GATT server; on the client-side, I use `bluetoothctl` to connect to the server-side (as follows)

```
[bluetooth]# connect C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45
Attempting to connect to C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45
[CHG] Device C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45 Connected: yes
[ABCDEF123456789
[CHG] Device C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45 Name: ABCDEF123456789
[ABCDEF123456789
[CHG] Device C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45 Alias: ABCDEF123456789
[ABCDEF123456789
[CHG] Device C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45 ServicesResolved: yes
[ABCDEF123456789
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[ABCDEF123456789
[CHG] Device C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45 ServicesResolved: no
[ABCDEF123456789
[CHG] Device C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

However, the ble connection always disconnects automatically after the connection just established; on the other hand, if I use `hcitool` to connect to the server-side (as follows), it can successfully connect.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# hcitool lecc C0:EE:40:3A:D0:45
Connection handle 64
root@raspberrypi:~# bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller C0:EE:40:3B:39:5D Pairable: yes
[ABCDEF123456789]#
```

My question is, why the connection established by bluetoothctl break? Is there anything I missed to start a ble connection using bluetoothctl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default the RPi is both BR/EDR (classic) and LE Bluetooth. When acting as a BLE peripheral it is good to configure the controller to Bluetooth Low Energy only. It has been discovered that to get a reliable connection to other devices that support both types of Bluetooth, this is required. This configuration change is done in the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file. Ensure that the file contains the following:

```
ControllerMode = le
```

This can also be done on the command line with:

```
$ sudo btmgmt power off
$ sudo btmgmt bredr off
$ sudo btmgmt power on
```